# Hibernate - open sessions vs current sessions and current session context

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, session

I have a spring managed web app where we're using Hibernate. In my `hibernate.cfg.xml` we have

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

It's also configured to use HikariCP connection pooling.

When we open sessions, we follow the paradigm of this. Note that I'm not explicitly closing the session.

```
Transaction tx = null;
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
try {
  tx = session.beginTransaction();
  // do DB stuff.
  tx.commit(); // or, sometimes session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (tx != null) {
        tx.rollback();
    }
    throw new CustomDbException(e);
}
```

In some cases, when closing the session, we do `session.getTransaction().commit()` at a minimum, this is incosistent, but I'm not sure if it's giving a different trasancation or otherwise causing some problems.

We've been seeing intermittent issues with `LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement`, `StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)`, and `TransactionException: nested transactions not supported`. We're not trying to do nested exceptiosn and always clean up the transaction, but I'm starting to think that maybe the sessions is being shared.

The application is multi threaded, and I'm starting to suspect that `getCurrentSession` is actually being shread across threads. I was under the impression that by setting `hibernate.current_session_context_class` to thread, then getCurrentSession() would provide a separate session per thread. Should I be taking a different approach here? Should I be using `openSession()` instead, or somehow configuring hibernate to give me unique sessions per thread?

We use `@JmsListener` methods, and the transactional exceptions seem most prevalent there, but are not localized there.

Exact hibernate versions are as follows:

`hibernate:   [ 'org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.4.Final',
                     'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.11.Final',
                     'org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:4.3.11.Final'],
      hikari:        'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.4.1',`

Comment: When you are opening session you should also be closing them, if you don't your session and connection will be leaked. What is even worse in a web environment threads are being reused. So the next request can be handled by the same thread that handled the previous request. As you aren't closing your session it is still attached to the thread and thus being reused/shared. But why aren't you simply using Spring to manage that for you? Saves you a lot of headaches...

Comment: Currently, I don't know when i'm opening a sesssion. I believe 'get current session' opens a new session only if needed, or just returns the current session for... the thread? 

How would I have spring managed that for me?

Comment: Annotate the method with `@Transactional`. Only use `getCurrentSession` and remove `<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>` from your configuration. Spring will open the session at the start of `@Transactional` and close it at the end of the method. Multiple `@Transactional` methods called from an already annotated method will participate in the same transaction.

Comment: But without having it spring managed with @Transactional, the way I have it now, is it not doing a session per thread?

Comment: Yes but as you aren't closing it those are leaking (and you are also leaking connections) and as threads are reused in a web container trouble is bound to happen. However letting spring manage them you will get the a session per thread, it cleans your code (only `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession` remains) is less error prone and connections / sessions aren't leaked.

Comment: "Yes but as you aren't closing it those are leaking". Sorry, I don't understand. Even if threads are reused in the web application, is it actually harmful to reuse the session (assuming that's what's happening).

Comment: also, java threads can't be reused. Unless you mean just reusing thread IDs?

Comment: I suggest you do a little reading on how servlet containers work. In short they have a thread pool, each request takes a thread from the pool, when finished it is returned to the pool. So threads are resused between different requests. So is reuse of the Hibernate session bad, yes it is. Never reuse sessions... It can even be dangerous if you are working in a multi tenant environment or per user connection. Also open sessions keep connections open, so if you have a smaller connection pool eventually you will run out of connections.